# Why does simply looking at my Storyboard in XCode 5 ruin my app?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7

I have an app built in XCode 4 against iOS6. If I open that workspace in XCode 5, clean and build my project, and run it in the simulator, it works (looks a bit different and needs some work, but it works). If I the simply navigate to my Storyboard and **do absolutely nothing else**, running the app in the simulator again results in my Photo Slideshow showing up black rather than showing pictures properly. A diff reveals it made some changes to the story board file when I looked at it. Rolling back the changes pertaining to my slideshow only is not effective. Rolling back all the changes works until I look at the Storyboard again.

It's obviously capable of working properly - why does it have to ruin everything just because I look at the Storyboard? Now I have to rebuild this part of the app, which is painful because I didn't build this part of the app to start with. This is not great for maintainability.

Comment: I'm really sorry, but your question simply asks for an answer like - 'Have you tried opening your Storyboard and looking away from the screen?" But if we are serious, the problems are more deep rooted here, I think. Chances are you might need to review your whole Storyboard file to find out what's wrong.

Comment: when it goes black does the app actually crash? When updating to Xcode5 there are changes made to the storyboard to make it no longer accessible in older versions of Xcode 4.x. There is a warning that backs that too. Try going into the simulator and reset the sim then complete the storyboard update and try again

Comment: @@SergiusGee Basically, selecting the Storyboard file in the navigator triggers some sort of migration that is not trigger by building. And the frustrating thing is that migration is obviously not neeeded since the app works great if I do not trigger the migration. I understand that I have to dive into the Storyboard and fix what's wrong, but it's not clear why this is necessary since it's clearly able to work before doing its migration.

Comment: @@StuartM The app does not crash (though you are stuck and you have to kill it - no navigation is available), and there are no warnings that I see.

Answer (score 1):

OK I have been messing with this all day.

In a nut shell keep or install Xcode 4.6 to deploy iOS 6.1 and before apps.

So for Xcode 5 messing stuff up, yes it's not working as expected.
I would expect to set the target
[image]

And have it look like an ios 6.1 app but it does not it looks ok in the viewer but both on the simulator and a iPad it looks bad. I have already filed a bug report.

ALSO if you have Autolayout checked in your 4.6 project and then try to look at it in Xcode 5.0 be prepared to kill Xcode as it tries to move everything around. In my case many table views got stuck in an endless loop and finally got a warning that tables can not exceed 10,000 :)